# I want to copy from array to char

Tags: c++

Hello guys and sorry if my English are not that good .

I am trying to make a program that has 5 players and each player has 5 random ints 
that sum up for each player . Then I want to check who has the most points and print his name with a message .

I am trying to do :

```
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    if (p[i].sum>p[i+1].sum)
    {
       strcpy(p[i].name,winner);
    }
    else strcpy(p[i+1].name, winner);
}
cout << "The winner is : " << winner << endl;
```

but the winner value does not change . 
here is a screenshot http://prntscr.com/abxqd3

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To get better answers, you should include the type of p, at least.

Comment: Using std::string instead of C style strings would probably make your job easier.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, including structure and variable definitions.

Comment: This isn't the right way to find the maximum. This will find the greater of the last two elements it compares. It will compare the last element to an out-of-bounds one on its right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of 'winner' won't obviously change as you are not modifying its value anywhere and your code's logic to find the maximum element is incorrect. If you are trying to find the maximum and copy the name to winner variable you should try this

```
int max = 0;     // index of the largest sum, initially assumed to be 0
for (int i=1;i<5;i++)
{
 if (p[i].sum>p[max].sum)
 {
  max = i;
 }
}
strcpy(winner, p[max].name);
cout << "The winner is : " << winner << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) I am still a beginner so I am making some silly mistakes :P 
I implemented the changes that you suggested and it works like a charm . 

Thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome and everyone makes mistakes, it's how you learn new things. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I think first you should fix your logical error. You just compare the sum of player i and it's next player.It does not make sense.

for example consider you have these sum scores 8,3,1,4,6. so in first iteration you set winner with the name of player 0 which it has value 8 but in next iteration set 3 and so on. in last iteration you got the name of player with 6  score but you should have player with 8 score.

So always You have the player name with bigger score between to last element of array as winner.

you should define an object with player type for storing  player with max sum like pmax and change the if condition as bellow

```
if (p[i].sum>pmax.sum)
{
    pmax.name=p[i].name;
    pmax.sum=p[i].sum;
}
cout << "The winner is : " << pmax.name << endl;
```

Comment: `winner` appears to be a string rather than an object.